# Как на странице отобразить данные, введённые на другой странице?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, плагин

Как сделать так чтобы вводимые циферки посетителям сайта выводились на другой странице в WP.

Пользователь на странице ввёл число, переходит на другую, и на ней отображается то, что он вводил.

Может есть какие-нибудь плагины для этого?

Comment: Чего-чего надо? Опиши нормально задачу. Исправь вопрос.

Comment: Можно хранить в куки, сессиях, локалсторедже или кеше. Учите пыху)